# Using Node.js with Gulp, Babel, Webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack, gulp, babeljs

Some Node.js projects use things like Babel, Gulp, Webpack. Other Node.js projects don't use such things. Do I have to use them in my Node.js projects and why? Perhaps you know different cases when I should take one of these decision?

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need.

Webpack is a bundler, it is intended to help packing up multiple files into one single file. Throughout this process you can transpile the code to apply modifications on it, eg: convert from es6 to es5 (if needed).

To transpile your code from es6 to es5, you are going to need [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/index.html#babel-is-a-javascript-compiler), where you can do a lot of stuff with that.

Gulp is a task runner/manager, not used that often since most of people use webpack nowadays. But still useful for a bunch of stuff.

If you are going to develop pure node.js projects, you don't have to worry about this. For web you should be aware of all of these tools.

Answer (score 1):

I've found Babel, Gulp, Webpack can be used in Node.js projects with cases:

- you need to minimize production code.
- you'd like to use all ES6+ features (like 'export' and 'import', decorators).
- you want to use JavaScript extensions like TypeScript.
- If for some reason your project contains  `.js` files are intended to run in different environments (Node.js, casperjs, browsers), you would like to use ES6+ inside all `.js` files.